# Displaying Color Picker using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, frontend

I have an Html page that uses AngularJS and Typescript how to display color picker using AngularJs?

Comment: Have you tried the same yourself? If so, try to include that code also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `angular-bootstrap-colorpicker` component

https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker